# Unable to parse List type into mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, list, tuples

I am trying to insert data from records those are having lists or tuples in the data.I have tried with the following code:

Code:

```
import mysql.connector

#Create connection, added db we created#
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost', 
    user='root', 
    password='123', 
    database='testdb_1'
    ) 

#Create cursor for the connection
my_cursor = connection.cursor()

#Create SQL statement with placeholders and put in variable 
mike_placeholders="INSERT INTO users (name,emails,ranksheld) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) "

    #Create list (array) of records
    records_list = [('Tim',['Tim@tim.com', 'tim12@tim12.com'],[2,3]), ('Mary',['Mary@mary.com'],[40, 45, 52]), ('Sam',['Sam@sam.com'],None), ('Fred',['Fred@fred.com'],[4]) ]

    #Execute cursor, requires SQl statement variable, record variable
    my_cursor.executemany(mike_placeholders,records_list)

    #Commit the connection to make the change on the database
    connection.commit()
```

When I tried to execute this i got following error:

```
InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Python type list cannot be converted
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to use `tuple` instead of `list`. So, `records_list` should be`(('Tim',['Tim@tim.com', 'tim12@tim12.com'],[2,3]), ('Mary',['Mary@mary.com'],[40, 45, 52]), ('Sam',['Sam@sam.com'],None), ('Fred',['Fred@fred.com'],[4]) )`

Comment: It appears the problem is with the `emails` and `ranksheld` columns where you are passing for each of these lists instead of single values.

Comment: Does the `emails` column for example contain multiple emails separated by some separator such as a comma?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have arrays in tuples. If you want to insert multiple rows with the same name/email, you have to add additional tuples in your array. Example:

```
import mysql.connector

#Create connection, added db we created#
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost', 
    user='root', 
    password='123', 
    database='testdb_1'
    ) 

#Create cursor for the connection
my_cursor = connection.cursor()

#Create SQL statement with placeholders and put in variable 
mike_placeholders="INSERT INTO users (name,emails,ranksheld) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) "

    #Create list (array) of records
    records_list = [('Tim','Tim@tim.com',2), ('Tim', 'tim12@tim12.com',3), ('Mary','Mary@mary.com',40), ('Mary','Mary@mary.com', 45), ('Mary','Mary@mary.com', 52), ('Sam','Sam@sam.com',None), ('Fred','Fred@fred.com',4) ]

    #Execute cursor, requires SQl statement variable, record variable
    my_cursor.executemany(mike_placeholders,records_list)

    #Commit the connection to make the change on the database
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: The prepared statement takes 3 parameters and you are passing 4 in the first case. I think for example the `emails` column based on its name is meant to hold multiple values even though this makes it not event first normal form.

Comment: Yeah, that was mistake on my part. Even though if `emails` is supposed to hold multiple values, the data is not configured  correctly. From SQL query `(%s, %s, %s)` it expects 3 parameters so if you want to add multiple emails -> concatenate them.